# Spherical harmonics with 2 cosmological probes : considering $a_{\ell m, photo}$ as a constant and $\hat{a}_{\ell m, spectro}$ as an estimator

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, statistics, noise, spherical-harmonics

I am in cosmological context where the survey on which I am working has 2 probes : a photometric galaxy clustering ($GC_{ph}$) probe and a spectroscopic galaxy clustering ($GC_{sp}$ probe).

We use an unbiased estimator $\mathcal{\hat{D}}$ which is well known from data. This estimator is defined by ( sp = spectroscopic probe and ph = photometric probe) :

$$\mathcal{\hat{D}}=\dfrac{\hat{a}_{\ell m, sp}^{2}}{a_{\ell m,ph}^{2}}$$

A colleague told me that if we neglect the Poisson noise (or Shot noise) for photometric probe (ph) and not neglect the Poisson noise for spectroscopic probe, then, we could write the variance of $\mathcal{\hat{D}}$ under the form :

$$\operatorname{Var}(\mathcal{\hat{D}})=\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{\hat{a}_{\ell m, \mathrm{sp}}^{2}}{a_{\ell m, \mathrm{ph}}^{2}}\right)=\frac{\left\langle\hat{a}_{\ell m, \mathrm{sp}}^{4}\right\rangle}{a_{\ell m, \mathrm{ph}}^{4}}-\frac{\left\langle\hat{a}_{\ell m, \mathrm{sp}}^{2}\right\rangle\left\langle\hat{a}_{\ell m, \mathrm{sp}}^{2}\right\rangle}{a_{\ell m, \mathrm{ph}}^{4}}=\frac{2}{f_{\mathrm{sky}} n_{\mathrm{galaxies, sp}}^{2} a_{\ell m, \mathrm{ph}}^{4}}\quad(1)$$

When I say that photometric can be neglicted for photometric probe, it is due to the huge number of galaxies shapes collected compared to spectroscopic probe.

So the Poisson noise (called also "Shot noise") for spectroscopic is very larger compared to photometric since the expression of this noise is :

$$P_{shot\,noise}=\dfrac{1}{n_{galaxies}^{2}}$$ with $n_{galaxies}$ is the density of galaxies observed.

If you take a small density (like for spectroscopic probe), the noise will be large.

On the contrary, with photometric probe, we have a huge number of galaxies.

As a conclusion, I would like to understand the justification that we can assimilate $a_{\ell m,ph}$ as a constant in the expression of variance $(1)$, and so we have the well known relation :

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(a\,X\right)=a^2\,\operatorname{Var}(X)$$ like into (1).

But I repeat, how can we justify the $a_{\ell m,ph}$ as constant ? I have difficulties to grasp this approximation.

If someone could explain me this result, this would be fine to tell it.

**PS** : if it can be useful, we can demonstrate also this :

Using Wick's Theorem on term $\left\langle\hat{a}_{\ell m, \mathrm{sp}}^{4}\right\rangle$, we have :

$$
\begin{gathered}
\Rightarrow \frac{3\left\langle\hat{a}_{\ell m, \mathrm{sp}}^{2}\right\rangle^{2}-\left\langle\hat{a}_{\ell m, \mathrm{sp}}^{2}\right\rangle^{2}}{a_{\ell m, \mathrm{ph}}^{4}}=\frac{2}{f_{\mathrm{sky}} n_{\mathrm{galaxies,sp}}^{2} a_{\ell m, \mathrm{ph}}^{4}} \\
\Rightarrow\left\langle\hat{a}_{\ell m, \mathrm{sp}}^{2}\right\rangle^{2}=\frac{1}{f_{\mathrm{sky}} n_{\mathrm{galaxies,sp}}^{2}}
\end{gathered}
$$